# Different sample number for each group in a data set

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

Given a dataset

```
key <- rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 10)
value <- sample(30)
df <- data.frame(key, value)
```

I would like a different number of samples for each group in keys, a simple code using dplyr that obviously do not work for this task is

```
ns <- c('a'= 1, 'b'= 2, 'c' = 3)
df %>%
mutate(n_s = ns[key]) %>%
group_by(key) %>%
sample_n(n_s)
```

There is some solution that can look as simple as that ?

Comment: A data.table version for fun - `df[df[, sample(.I, ns[match(unlist(.BY), names(ns))]), by=key]$V1,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapply` and with `split(df, df$key)` and `ns` as arguments, but note that the names of `ns` are not use.  It's the order of the groups that counts, and if the number of groups doesn't match the length of ns, ns will be recycled.

```
set.seed(129)
mapply(sample_n, split(df, df$key), ns, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>%
  rbind_all
#     key value
#  (fctr) (int)
#1      a    29
#2      b    14
#3      b    22
#4      c    10
#5      c    24
#6      c     3
```

Comment: Sweet! This solution will be more general if you to order ns by names ns[order(names(ns))]

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the `stratified` function from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
ns <- c('a'= 1, 'b'= 2, 'c' = 3)
stratified(df, "key", size = ns)
#    key value
# 1:   a     7
# 2:   b    10
# 3:   b    13
# 4:   c     4
# 5:   c    20
# 6:   c     9
```